# Parsing string list in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to remove the comments when printing this list.

I am using

```
output = self.cluster.execCmdVerify('cat /opt/tpd/node_test/unit_test_list')
for item in output:
    print item
```

This is perfect for giving me the entire file, but how would I remove the comments when printing?

I have to use cat for getting the file due to where it is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `self.cluster.execCmdVerify` obviously returns an `iterable`, so you can simply do this:

```
import re

def remove_comments(line):
    """Return empty string if line begins with #."""
    return re.sub(re.compile("#.*?\n" ) ,"" ,line)
    return line

data = self.cluster.execCmdVerify('cat /opt/tpd/node_test/unit_test_list')

for line in data:
    print remove_comments(line)
```

The following example is for a string output:

To be flexible, you can create a file-like object from the a string (as far as it is a string)

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import re

def remove_comments(line):
    """Return empty string if line begins with #."""
    return re.sub(re.compile("#.*?\n" ) ,"" ,line)
    return line

data = self.cluster.execCmdVerify('cat /opt/tpd/node_test/unit_test_list')
data_file = StringIO(data)

while True:
    line = data_file.read()
    print remove_comments(line)
    if len(line) == 0:
        break
```

Or just use `remove_comments()` in your `for-loop`.

Comment: This doesn't work well due to our testing framework and our systems are clustered with several nodes, so I cannot rlogin to the correct node within Python.

Comment: I used this buy I got this:

Comment: This error was obtained, any ideas?

   data_file = StringIO(data)
TypeError: expected read buffer, tuple found

Comment: `data` is obviously not a `string`, so just do it without `StringIO` with a for-loop. I'll update my post…

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex `re` module to identify comments and then remove them or ignore them in your script.

Answer (score 0):

What about greping the output

```
grep -v '#' /opt/tpd/node_test/unit_test_list
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a python file for example and you want to remove lines beginning with # you can try :

```
cat yourfile | grep -v '#'
```

EDIT:

if you don't need cat, you can directly do :

```
grep -v "#" yourfile
```

Comment: it's just for a text file located on a server.

Comment: why using cat when you can use grep directly?, I guess when Alan says he needs to use `cat`, he means that he can't use python to open the file directly, but can use other commands as far as I understand

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you absolutely had to use the cat command, this will still work though, when I said python file it was for the example of removing lines with #, it will still work with a textfile, just replace # by your comment syntax. But it would be best to use grep directly like egrep -v "#" yourfile.